# Class 'yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice' not found

Tags: yii2

> Class 'yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice' not found

i have used `vendor/yiisoft/yii2-authclient` but not working. Please help any persone if you know.

Comment: add your `view` file code here

Comment: <?= yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget([
     'baseAuthUrl' => ['site/auth'],
     'popupMode' => false,
]) ?> i've added this to view but saying Class 'yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice' not found

Comment: Edit the question and add your full `view` code in the question and that might give us some good idea of whats the problem there

Comment: look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: do you have "yiisoft/yii2-authclient": "*" in your composer.json?

Comment: in which composer.json there are many json file ..can you pls tell in which root?

Comment: i've used https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/blob/master/docs/guide/quick-start.md this process

Comment: go to your projects root directory in command prompt and run this command `composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-authclient`

Comment: follow installation guide first: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/blob/master/docs/guide/installation.md

Comment: can you give me skype id pls so we can discus pls

Comment: check your `components` array inside `config/web.php`. it must contain `'authClientCollection' => [
        'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
        'clients' => [
            ],`

Comment: Yii2 basic app or advanced app?

Comment: you have installed authClient using composer?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<?= \yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget([ 'baseAuthUrl' => ['site/auth'], 'popupMode' => false, ]) ?>
```

or add a proper use of the class you need

```
 use vendor/yiisoft/yii2-authclient;
```